# Flutter Local Notifications not scheduling notifications

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I am working on To Do Flutter app, and I am trying to implement flutter_local_notifications package, I made two simple functions, showSimpleNotification() to show simple notification and scheduleNotification() for scheduling notification after 5 seconds, the simple one works just fine but the scheduling one not working, is everything ok with the code?

```
static Future showSimpleNotification({
  required String title,
  required String body,
  required String payload,
}) async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
    channelDescription: 'your channel description', importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high, ticker: 'ticker');
  const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
  await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0,
    title,
    body,
    notificationDetails,
    payload: payload,
  );
}

static Future scheduleNotification({
  required String title,
  required String body,
  required String payload,
}) async {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    2,
    title,
    body,
    tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
    const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel 3',
        'your channel name',
        channelDescription: 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker',
      ),
    ),
    androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    payload: payload,
  );
}
```